# Difficulties returning a structure from a function within another structure

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert rectangles to polygons, but when I try running my conversion function, I get nonsense.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Polygon {
    int nPoints;
    int* xPoints;
    int* yPoints;

    Polygon(int nPoints, int* xPoints, int* yPoints) :
        nPoints(nPoints), xPoints(xPoints), yPoints(yPoints) {
    }
};

struct Shape {
    virtual Polygon toPolygon() = 0;
};

struct Rectangle : public Shape {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) :
        x(x), y(y), width(width), height(height) {
    }

    virtual Polygon toPolygon() {
        int xPoints[] = {x, x + width, x + width, x};
        int yPoints[] = {y, y, y + height, y + height};
        return Polygon(4, xPoints, yPoints);
    }
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    Rectangle rect = Rectangle(14, 8, 45, 64);
    Polygon polygon = rect.toPolygon();
    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.nPoints; i++) {
        std::cout << polygon.xPoints[i] << ", " << polygon.yPoints[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
14, 8
32588, 32588
6299872, -383502305
0, 32588
```

The points outputted are quite different from the points on the rectangle that I defined, and I'd appreciate if somebody could tell me why.

(If anybody is wondering why the Shape structure exists, it is because I plan to add more shapes once I get this system to work with rectangles.)

Comment: Stop using pointers and use containers such as `std::vector<int>` or `std::array`.  Your entire issue is due to improper usage of pointers.

Comment: In addition, your `Shape` class should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Also, using containers, you can actually 1) Check to see if the number of x-points equal to the number of y-points before you create a polygon, and 2) You don't need the `nPoints`, variable, since a container such as `vector` knows its own size by using the `size()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xPoints and yPoints are declared within your toPolygon method.  So they go out of scope once the method returns.  The pointers used to create the polygon then become undefined.

Comment: That was the problem. Using vectors for the points in the Polygon structure instead of pointers fixed it.